# NSMutableArray object not accessible in methods

Tags: objective-c, object, nsmutablearray

I have the following variable in my .h file:

```
NSMutableArray *arr;
```

Then I have a method in implementation:

```
void aMethod
{
    if (something)
    {
        arr= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0]; 
        [arr addObject:someObject];
    }
```

now if I try to access arr from any other method or even another if block within the same method, the app crashes and I can't access that arr. For example:

```
  //same method:
  if (something else)
  {
       SomeObject *obj = [arr objectAtIndex:0]; //<---- it crashes on this line
  }
```

Any light guys?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 errors here:

1. You have a leak

   arr= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  //<--here
2. it crashes cause you're creating autoreleased object and then try to access it when it is already deallocated:

   arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

remove this line:

```
arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

Comment: Or, if you want an `autoreleased` array then remove the `init` line, and keep the `arrayWithCapacity`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Now I am not getting a crash at that point. But as I access the object that I just retrieved from the array. I am getting the following in my debugger: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. Could it be NSMutableArray related?

Comment: it means that there is another bug somewhere else. you're probably over-releasing an object, that you added to array.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how I could be overreleasing an object?

Comment: This is how i am populating that array:

Comment: NSObject* obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
 NSArray* arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject: obj];
 [obj release];
 [obj release];
 NSLog(@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex: 0]); //crash here

Comment: Object *currentObject = [[Voyage alloc] init]; then I populate the object and then I do this: [arr addObject:currentObject]; all this is done in another method by the way. THanks in advance.

Comment: ahh i see, so my object is probably being released in that method, is there anyway to not release those objects? I am not explicitly releasing them.

Answer (score 2):

You're constructing the array twice. The following two lines:

```
arr= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

The first one constructs an empty array. The second one throws away the results of the first line, and constructs another empty array that is autoreleased - that is, does not live beyond the current method unless explicitly retained.

Wipe the `arrayWithCapacity` line, it'll work as expected. Don't forget to release in `dealloc`.

Answer (score 2):

The  second init of the array forms an auto released instance.

Do this

```
-(id)init
{
self = [super init];
if(self)
{
   arr = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5] retain];
}
return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
[arr release];
[super dealloc];
}

-(void)aMethod
{
if (something)
{     
   [arr addObject:someObject];
}
}
```